# DataFrame calculus for sentiment analysis Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sentiment-analysis, tweets

I have the following problem with Sentiment Analysis of tweets, using a list of words having words and values (positive or negative).
I tried the following code to create DataFrames and it works. But do you have an idea about the calculus?

**What I have to do is to identify if a tweet contains a word from a wordlist. If it contains some words from the wordlist, then sum the values assigned to each word and print the result (tweet | sum). Any idea??**

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import json

sentimientos = open('Desktop/Ejercicio1/Sentimientos.txt')
dfis = list(map(lambda x: x.replace('\n', '').split('\t'), sentimientos))
dfis1 = DataFrame(dfis)
dfis1

for line in open('Desktop/Ejercicio1/salida_tweets.json', 'r'):
    try:
       tweet=json.loads(line)
       tweets.append(tweet)
    except:
       continue
tweet = tweets[0]

ids= [tweet['id_str'] for tweet in tweets if 'id_str' in tweet]
text= [tweet['text'] for tweet in tweets if 'text' in tweet]

    df=pd.DataFrame({'Ids':pd.Index(ids), 'Ids':pd.Index(ids)})
    df
```

Example of the word list:

abandon -2

abandoned -2

abandons -2

abducted -2

Example of a tweet text:
@Brenamae_ I WHALE SLAP YOUR FIN AND TELL YOU ...